# Can you make a bump map texture emit light in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, light

So I thought if I can use a bump map to create, uh, bumps on a surface... I thought I could somehow make it glow/emit light?

Is there a node for that, or maybe there's a method to do that?

Comment: the emission node is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an emission node, with a mix shader node (use the map map for the factor input). Now your object will emit light based on the bump map.

[image]

Comment: So uhh yeah this kinda works... but its not really emitting light. I don't see any light on the ground or on other surfaces, its just kind of really bright....

Comment: Hey man, I think this is a fantastic idea that should be explored, shoot me a line at www.zemaraim.com if you'd like to collaborate a bit :) (I hope I am permitted to post my website here)...

Comment: Thing is, I'd like to use the emission along with glossy and anisotropic nodes... kinda new to blender, so still not sure how things work correctly here.... tiny bit too complex..

Comment: @PeterGašperan Try upping the Emission strength. If that doesn't work, something else is wrong. You can send my a .blend file (I'm sending you an email)

Comment: I am sorry man, just realised I did not had the email set in the contact form on my homepage, re-installed it just recently and forgot to set it, I appologize greatly!

Comment: @PeterGašperan no problem, I just sent an email directly :)

Comment: Strange, did not receive anything... Just tested, it should work. Did you used info [at] zemaraim [dot] com?

Comment: Yes. Try sending me [an email](http://giantcowfilms.com/contact/) instead, and I will reply. Maybe that will work.

Comment: Right. Thx man!